# is it possible to configure the default sorting of the file list at gnome's Open File dialog?

Tags: gnome-shell

I want the file list to be displayed always sorted by "modified" column (descending).

My `gnome-shell` version is:

```
Package: gnome-shell
Version: 3.4.2-7+deb7u1
```

Comment: Yes, in my system looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/L8xUztt.png), but I guess it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the `gtk+` file chooser dialog settings and specify the sort column (in this case `modified`).

- for `gtk3+` apps:

via `dconf-editor`, navigate to *org > gtk > settings > file-chooser* and set *sort-column* to `modified` and *sort-order to* `descending`

[image]

or via `gsettings`, in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-column 'modified'
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-order 'descending'
```

- for `gtk2+` apps:

via editing the configuration file `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`:

```
SortColumn=modified
SortOrder=descending
```

Comment: I see these configurations and I have set them to `modified` and `descending`. These seem to work for `gedit` but not for other software like OpenOffice or Iceweasel. Is that expected?

Comment: re-tested at OO and Iceweasel and they work like a charm now. Thanks a lot.